# Unable to make cross-domain ajax post because of CORS error to Rails app on Heroku

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've done all kind of searching and can't seem to figure this one out.

I'm trying to create a widget that you can put on any website to get feedback from users, which will post the feedback to my app at waterloo.herokuapp.com where users can log in to see all of their feedback.

I'm using a jquery ajax POST method to my Rails app with the following code:

```
fb_form.submit(function(ev) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://waterloo.herokuapp.com/domains/2/comments',
    data: fb_form.serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      alert('cool, this worked');
      $('.feedback-container').hide();
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

and I'm getting the following error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://waterloo.herokuapp.com/domains/2/comments. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.will-wallace.com' is therefore not allowed access.

In my comments_controller, I have a set_headers before_filter which should allow a post from any domain (and works locally):

```
def set_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'Etag'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*, x-requested-with, Content-Type, If-   Modified-Since, If-None-Match'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '86400'
end
```

The weirdest thing is, when I log in to see the feedback that I was attempting to post, it actually succeeded. Nonetheless, I am getting an ajax error response as I mentioned before.

The domain I'm testing the widget on is will-wallace.com, if it helps at all to go and actually fiddle around with it.

Lastly, if it helps at all, I seem to be getting a 500 error by tailing the heroku logs:

```
2014-07-10T01:39:59.624512+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/domains/2/comments" host=waterloo.herokuapp.com fwd="96.255.218.195" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=63ms status=500 bytes=1543
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your website, when I use the widget I see the same error message in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://waterloo.herokuapp.com/domains/2/comments. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.will-wallace.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

But if you look at the actual response, its getting a 500 error from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 10 Jul 2014 02:40:45 GMT
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2014-05-14)
X-Request-Id: 66b02889-e2e9-4cac-b38f-3e5370982b55
X-Runtime: 0.052554
Content-Length: 1266
Connection: keep-alive
```

This is a bit misleading. It looks like you are setting your headers correctly, but since your server is getting an error, it either never gets to that code or ignores custom headers on errors. **If you Fix your 500 error, you should see your `Access-Control` headers start showing up in the response.**

On a sided note, WEBrick isn't the best server for production, best for development mode only.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Based on your advice I removed the mail send line for the successful create action in the controller. Apparently it's not configured for prod and that was causing the 500. Very much apprecitated.